# Select by latest timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following table :

```
+-------+--------+---------------------+
| score |  user  |      scrap_time     |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  200  |  Bob   | 2015-09-08 11:46:17 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  210  |  Alice | 2015-09-08 11:46:17 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  240  |  Bob   | 2015-09-08 11:48:00 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  260  |  Alice | 2015-09-08 11:48:01 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to get all the scores for *each user* that have the *latest* `scrap_time` and ignore the older ones.

Example:

```
+-------+--------+---------------------+
| score |  user  |      scrap_time     |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  240  |  Bob   | 2015-09-08 11:48:00 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  260  |  Alice | 2015-09-08 11:48:01 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
```

I have been trying to come up with a query, like this one :

```
select * from scores where date(scrap_time) = ( select max(scrap_time) from scores);
```

But this does not give me the results I need.

Comment: How come `Bob` is also included in the expected result set?

Comment: Because i need the last score for every user

Comment: `select score,max(scrap_time),user from scores`

Comment: @Saty : this returns only one result , i need to select all the users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find MAX(scrap_time) per user and then find those rows

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE (user,scrap_time) IN (
 SELECT user,MAX(scrap_time) scrap_time FROM scores
 GROUP BY user);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `MAX(scrap_time)` per `user`, then simply join back to your table to get the required result set. Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT s.score, s.user, s.scrap_time 
FROM scores AS s
INNER JOIN (SELECT user, max(scrap_time)  AS maxTime
            FROM scores
            GROUP BY user) AS t
ON s.user = t.user AND s.scrap_time = maxTime
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bf7b4/3)

Answer (score 0):

use max function with group by which will provide u recent time of each score

```
 select   score, user, max(scrap_time) 
 from     scores  
 group by score;
```